# AnalysisException error occurs when querying a table from Impala

Tags: hadoop, hive, impala

While describing or selecting impala table information i am getting following error.

I already tried refresh and invalidate metadata statements but these attempts didn't solve my problem.

> ERROR: AnalysisException: Failed to load metadata for table:
>    CAUSED BY: TableLoadingException: Failed to load metadata
>   for table: . Running 'invalidate metadata ' may
>   resolve this problem. CAUSED BY: NullPointerException: null

Comment: can you check whether your impala version is compatible with hadoop?......

Comment: problem is not that.i am accessing all tables except one table

Comment: Can you access the table from Hive? Try getting its DDL with `SHOW CREATE TABLE`. Can you reproduce on another (empty) table created with the same `CREATE TABLE` construct. Please post the statement here and try simplifying it until the problem disappears.